# restrict access for some products if user haven't meta

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

We have a shop, that works with WordPress and WooCommerce.

Nearly every product calls api, that update clients database. But, we don't need to sell products to users, that haven't specified their "club_card" meta.

Is there a way to check, is user specified such meta, and restrict access to buy products, if not

Comment: This question is too broad. Try doing some research on your own and come back with more specific questions!

Comment: The reference to API and updating a client database are confusing. But the last sentence is pretty specific: How to restrict purchasing certain products to users with certain user meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to wait until the item is being added and then re-direct. You can validate whether the item can be added on the `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation` filter. The rest of your logic is pretty valid.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'so_34505885_add_to_cart_validation' ), 10, 6 );
function so_34505885_add_to_cart_validation( $passed_validation, $product_id, $product_quantity, $variation_id = '', $variations = array(), $cart_item_data = array() ) {

        // If product tagged as for club members
        if (has_term( 'club-only', 'product_tag', $product_id )){
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( !$current_user || $current_user->club_card_number == ''){
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You must be a club member to purchase this product.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ), $mnm_item->get_title() ), 'error' );
                    $passed_validation = false;
            }
        }
        return $passed_validation;
}
```

Or even better still you could completely prevent the add to cart buttons from even working on items that can't be purchased by toggling whether or not the product is purchasable.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'so_34505885_is_purchasable' ), 10, 2 );
function so_34505885_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product_id ) {

        // If product tagged as for club members
        if (has_term( 'club-only', 'product_tag', $product_id )){
            $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
            if ( !$current_user || $current_user->club_card_number == ''){
                wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You must be a club member to purchase this product.', 'your-plugin-textdomain' ), $mnm_item->get_title() ), 'error' );
                    $purchasable = false;
            }
        }
        return $purchasable;
}
```

Comment: great! thank you! your solution really looks more logic than mine ;)

Answer (score 0):

At last i use this solution:

we add new action on `woocommerce_add_to_cart` hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'on_add_to_cart_check_club_info', 10,2);
```

and check every product, if there is a tag that says, that this one is for club users only:

```
function on_add_to_cart_check_club_info($cart_item_key, $product_id)
{
    // If product tagged as for club members
    if (has_term( 'club-only', 'product_tag', $product_id ))
    {
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
        if (!$current_user || $current_user->club_card_number == '')
        {
            // Drop to the same page if user haven't specified club card number
            header('Location: '.get_permalink($product_id));
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See my answer. Both options provide a better user experience.